# How can I within Drupal 7 make updates to an external MS SQL Server database?

Tags: 7, database

I have an external MS SQL Server database that I can display some of its contents within the Drupal 7 views module via the [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) module.

How can I within Drupal 7 make updates to an external MS SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Drupal database API to manipulate the data in the other database. You can use [db_set_active()](https://www.drupal.org/node/18429) to switch to the other database.

Comment: Instead of using db_set_active() to switch to the other database I think a better approach is the recommended answer within this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839063/multiple-concurrent-database-connections-in-drupal-7

Comment: I was citing the official handbook. That said, weird things can happen to things like watchdog() while you are connected to the other database with db_set_active(). And, this question is actually a duplicate of the one you linked.